# Asp add header to response not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to add header in filter:

```
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

But it is not appears in the browser, not chrome , and not in Firefox:

[image]

**this is how i return json:**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult GetMetaData()
{

        var result = new BL().GetMetaData();
        string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
        return Content(response, "application/json");

}
```

Comment: no gzip-ing is not done by doing `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");` really. read this [answer about http compression on iis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580169/4648586) for better understanding.

Comment: you can't just add a header saying the content is gzipped, if it isn't actually, physically, gzipped. Headers are there to provide information to the recipient, they don't actually _do_ anything. If you want to do this you need to actually zip your content as well, as Bagus mentioned.

Comment: I do compress :Response.Filter = new GZipStream(Response.Filter,CompressionMode.Compress);